# A ring $R$ with a product that is non commutative, non associative, and with no unit element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

For $R = \mathbb Z_2 \times \mathbb Z_2$ we can define a product by the following table:

\begin{matrix}
\cdot  & a & b & c & d \\
a & a & a & a & a \\
b & a & a & d & d \\
c & a & a & c & c \\
d & a & a & b & b
\end{matrix}

where $a = (0,0), b = (0,1), c= (1,0), d= (1,1). $ We can verify that $R$ is indeed a ring. I've checked that this product is not commutative: $bc=d\neq a = cb,$ is not associative: $(db)c = ac = a \neq b = dd = d(bc)$ and clearly does not have a unit element.

> My question is: Can I generalize this result? Is there a result concerning those kind of products (non-associative, non-commutative and non-unital)  for a ring $R$ with more than 4 elements?

**Observation:** I am asking this because my professor posed us a question to define such a product on $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$. At the end of the exercise, he asked: Can you generalize for $R$ with $\geq4 $ elements?

Comment: Why call it a ring if it has none of those nice properties? I suppose in general, that if you define a "product" at random, then you shouldn't expect it to be commutative, you shouldn't expect it to be associative and shouldn't expect it to be unital.

Comment: This operation does not distribute over addition: $b+c = d$ and $a(b+c) = ad = a$ while $ab + ac = a + a = 0$.  Also $(b+c)a = da = a$ while $ba+ca = a+a = 0$. Therefore it makes absolutely no sense how "We can verify that $R$ is indeed a ring."  What is your definition of a ring? Having a binary operation on an abelian group is *not* enough to call the system a ring under all conventions I have ever heard.

Comment: @KCd why is it wrong? we have $a=0$, as it is the identity of the sum. For me you have just verified that $a(b+c) =a+ a = a = ab+ac$

Comment: Ah, whoops! Sorry. I wasn't even paying attention to what $a$ actually was there.  If your multiplication is genuinely distributive over addition but lacks any other decent properties (esp. being nonassociative and no identity) I would *not* consider it to be a ring at all.  Call it a Z-algebra, but definitely not a ring.  Please read https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.0135.

Comment: What do we want to "generalize", that there exist a structure $*$ on a given abelian group which does not have all properties in a list? (Which abelian groups shall we consider, all of the shape $\Bbb Z/m\times \Bbb Z/m$? Which is the list of properties that should not hold?) Please try to state a clear  proposition, that should be generalized.